# How do you use multiple monitors in MS Remote Desktop Connection Manager 2.7?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

Using the RDMan from:

```
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=44989
```

Tools->Options->Full Screen->  last checkbox is 'Use multiple monitors when necessary'

however this has no effect.

**This question is specifically in reference to RDMan, a Microsoft exe that manages multiple RDP sessions from one window  (NOT windows's builtin rdp, i.e. mstsc from the runline, they are different softwares).

Works fine using mstsc:

RDMan is on Win7

Host is on WinServer 2008 R2

Comment: What versions of Windows 7? Check http://superuser.com/questions/804204/cant-get-multiple-monitors-to-work-with-windows-remote-desktop/804343#804343

Comment: Hi, updated the question, it is for RDMan (not for mstsc).

Comment: I meant what version of windows 7 (it's edition, home,pro, ultimate) are you connecting to on the other side. Multiple monitors are only supported for remote Windows 7 Ultimate and Enterprise.

Comment: It works fine in mstsc

Comment: It'd be nice to see some actual documentation on this for the newest version. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/40de3859-b77c-4078-9cee-72bd8c4084f2/span-2-monitors-when-using-remote-desktop-connection-manager?forum=w7itprogeneral suggests it's not doable for the previous version. The post suggests using Remote Desktop Plus / mstsc

Comment: Thanks for that, I actually saw that and misread it to be applyting to mstsc but looks like it does apply to RDMan. Unrelatedly which I'll post in a question later (SO has a mandatory waiting period) I'm trying 'tightVNC' to share the host screen. Under 'Administration'->'Session Sharing', there's a radio option to 'always treat connections as shared, add new clients keep old connections' ... however connecting with this option checked brings to the Win login screen and not the current user's active screen, as desired.

Comment: re: above, problem is only when another user is connected through mstsc, two vnc users can connect.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Option in the Settings [image]

And if you are sizing the Window over the two Monitors or get in Fullscreen you can use both Monitors

Answer (score 0):

The only way it works for me is to:

1. Manually set `Server properties -> Remote Desktop Settings -> Remote Desktop Size -> Custom` to, say, 3840x1200, assuming that your local monitor setup is a pair of 1920x1200 monitors.
2. Set a fullscreen hotkey in `Tools -> Options -> Full screen`
3. Run session and enter full-screen.

**The limitations:**

- Remote Desktop Size is limited to [4096x2048](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sysinternals/blob/3a1b0c81c6b019254acc981e01b8e229cb8fcbd7/sysinternals/downloads/rdcman.md#remote-desktop-settings)
- this limit is enforced at connection time, not during data entry
- only rectangular configurations are supported
- the remote system would not recognize you client's multi-monitor setup — any "Remote Desktop Size" would be treated as a single monitor (unlike Windows 10 built-in "mstc.exe" with it's great "Use all my monitors for the remote session" checkbox.

Tested in version 2.90, which is the most recent for 2022-06-11.

Of course, you can also just resize the RDCman window so that it spans across a number of your local monitors, but that would not allow you to overcome the limitations.

I've just also filed a [Better multi-monitor support](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sysinternals/issues/528) feature request with few more details. There's a tiny chance that they would fix this sometime.