# Using a subset of monitors for remote desktop

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, windows-10

I tried to find an answer to this a few years ago, but it seemed it wasn't possible then (I suspect it isn't now either! - but what the hell!)

I have a three monitor system, that I mostly use for remote desktop. However occasionally it would be useful to have remote desktop on two monitors and use the other monitor for the local machine.

I know it is possible to have a single monitor full screen, or to stretch an RDP session across monitors, but this loses things like snapping etc.

P.S. this is a duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/472346/remote-desktop-use-two-out-of-four-monitors) thread, but that was a couple of years ago, I'm hoping things have changed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The situation hasn't changed.  Your only two choices when using multiple monitors through an RDP session are the `/span` and `/multimon` options.

`/multimon` will treat each screen as a separate display just like you would have on the host.  You get snapping/clipping capabilities, but the downside is you can only use ALL of the screens for this.

`/span` allows you to use only two of your three screens, but the downside is that it's one big rectangle that spans across more than 1 screen.  You lose each screen's identity as a separate, distinct display.

You can modify the local group policy on the target computer to specify a maximum of 2 displays for use with the `/multimon` switch.  I don't know what that would look like on a 3-screen display however.  I suspect the 3rd screen would just go black.  You'd have to play with this yourself.

You can get to the local group policy by hitting Start -> Run and typing `gpedit.msc`.  The setting you're looking for is Computer Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Remote Session Environment.  Set `Limit Maximum Number of Monitors` to enabled and specify 2.

**NOTE** You do this on the *host* computer (the one you're connecting to), not the client.

Comment: I had a little moment of excitement as I wondered if they'd fixed the Maximum limit policy on Windows 10 (I'm connecting to a WIn10 desktop), but alas if you set that to anything it still limits it to a single screen

Comment: I'm sure it's probably very low on Microsoft's priorities list.  The reason `/multimon` requires all your screens is because your local computer's window manager is in charge of rendering GUI elements on the remote host.  It lowers overhead because the host does not have to send pixels over the wire for drawing things like title bars and buttons.  It just sends the raw GDI info and your computer renders it.  That probably makes what you want harder for Microsoft to implement.

Comment: Its clearly very low on their priority list ;)  I was thinking it might have been something somebody had tweaked for Win10 (I live in hope!)

Comment: @WesSayeed How does one go about using /span mode?  When I try it, I'm restricted to a single monitor, even if my width is correct for 2 (I just get a scrollbar at the bottom, the window refuses to cross monitor boundaries during resize).

Answer (score 11):

You can:

- Save a .rdp connection file and check "Use multimonitor"
- Execute `mstsc /l` on the command line (list monitors, and show ID monitor)
- Edit .rdp file in notepad
- Change or add `selectedmonitors:s:1,2` after `use multimon:i:1`

In `selectedmonitors` you can select yours monitors, listed with `mstsc /l`. In my sample use 1,2 but you can use others.

More info: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/how-to-remote-desktop-fullscreen-rdp-with-just-some-of-your-multiple-monitors

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: What? In question said that is a duplicate. My answer is correct. I have 3 monitors and I use 2 with RDP.

Comment: In the other answer you failed to notice that the OP was using Windows 7 Pro which does not support multiple monitors in RDP. So your answer is useless.

Comment: This question is Windows10. Not Windows 7. See tag. Please read a little. The one who has difficulties with English is me.

Comment: I'm referring to [the other question which you answered](https://superuser.com/q/804204/337631) incorrectly where the OP was using Windows 7 Pro, not this question.

Comment: You only need donload last RDP Client: https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/2592687/remote-desktop-protocol-rdp-8-0-update-for-windows-7-and-windows-serve

Comment: I think my answer is proven to answer the question. Please undelete it.

Comment: In case someone else is in the same boat as me - if you have 3 monitors but want the RDP client to show up on monitors 2 and 3, add this line to your RDP file .. `selectedmonitors:s:0,2`

Comment: @abjbhat Thank you. I changed the wording a bit to make it clearer. I already wrote a lot of comments about this, but for now you are the first to help me explain it better ... despite my English.

Comment: Is there a way to get the output of `mstsc /l` as text, or some other way to process the output? I find the monitor IDs change frequently, apparently based on how quickly they respond to a wake-up call from my docking station.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the linked question, I have been using Vmware workstation to full screen on a subset of my monitors, running a stripped down version of Windows 7, it seems to be working well so far and I'll likely retain this as a solution (at least as something to use when I need to have that separation.)

It does get a little sluggish at times, but for the most part there is no difference in performance (I am primarily using office apps etc)

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is a very old one, but i've had this problem currently with thw windows 10 and found one answer that works like magic for me:

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/how-to-remote-desktop-fullscreen-rdp-with-just-some-of-your-multiple-monitors

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.