# Remote Desktop Client which allows to use some displays fullscreen

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

I am looking for a remote desktop client which allows to use two displays in fullscreen as remote, and use one display to run local apps.

[image]

So far I have tried

- Remote Desktop Connection (windows builtin)

This tool does not allow to specify the number of monitors you want to use. It only allows to use one screen, or all screens. Resizing the display is not possible.

- Windows 10 remote desktop app

This tool allows resizing, so it is possible to use two displays as remote, and one local. These two are however not used in fullscreen, resulting in weird resizing and fuzzy images.

- Remote Desktop Manager Free

Same issues as Windows 10 remote desktop app, no fullscreen for the specified monitors.

So the question is: does someone know an application which checks all these boxes?

1. Can be used in Windows 10
2. Small or no license cost
3. Allows to run some but not all displays in fullscreen mode

Comment: A well-formulated question, but it looks like we already have a few duplicates. If you do not believe they are applicable as duplicates, please edit your question with why. [Remote desktop use two out of four monitors](https://superuser.com/questions/472346/remote-desktop-use-two-out-of-four-monitors), [Using a subset of monitors for remote desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/969735/using-a-subset-of-monitors-for-remote-desktop)

Comment: Also, as [a comment](https://superuser.com/questions/472346/remote-desktop-use-two-out-of-four-monitors#comment1927381_472346) on one of the linked questions notes, there is [an open feature request](https://superuser.com/questions/472346/remote-desktop-use-two-out-of-four-monitors). If you want to see native support for this feature, you should vote for it.

Comment: Apparently I failed to link. Feature request can be found here: https://remotedesktop.uservoice.com/forums/301635-remote-desktop-for-windows-universal/suggestions/31424734-using-2-of-3-screens-on-terminal-server

Answer (score 0):

https://symless.com/synergy

It has all the features you asked for, I haven't tried it personally so I can't do a review. But they do sponsor lots of youtube video so they have big budgets, therefore they must be doing something right. They are constantly sponsoring Linus tech tips which is arguably the best tech channel on YouTube.

Again I cannot give a review I have never used it. But it looks like they are the best in the business.

Your other option is [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/), however I have never used it on multiple remote desktops in a setup like yours, so not sure if it works for you, but it's a great software.

Comment: We are working on servers, which we connect to with remote desktop. Synergy (as far as I know) is intended to replace a KVM-switch, and allow to use multiple local machines with one keyboard or mouse, each still using their own monitors.

I would like to connect to one remote machine using multiple but not all monitors.

Thanks for the suggestion anyway :)